# Write image metadata using JavaScript

Tags: image, image-processing, javascript

I'm trying to change image metadata using JavaScript libraries. I found enough libraries to read image metadata. But I couldn't find any JavaScript libraries to write image metadata. Are there any JS libraries exists to write image metadata?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript cannot write to files on the server without the help of a server side script. You need to implement writing the image metadata server-side.